# Analyzing XML schemas using org.eclipse.xsd and Maven2

Tags: java, xsd, eclipse-emf

I'm trying to implement the sample code to [this article](http://help.eclipse.org/help32/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.xsd.doc/references/articles/dwtip1-scpw/index.html) from 2002 (I know..), but cannot get the schema to load.

```
import org.eclipse.emf.common.util.URI;
import org.eclipse.emf.ecore.resource.Resource;
import org.eclipse.emf.ecore.resource.ResourceSet;
import org.eclipse.emf.ecore.resource.impl.ResourceSetImpl;
import org.eclipse.xsd.util.XSDResourceImpl;

    ResourceSet resourceSet = new ResourceSetImpl();
    // I replaced the deprecated createDeviceURI with createURI as recommended in JavaDoc
    XSDResourceImpl xsdSchemaResource = 
        (XSDResourceImpl)resourceSet.getResource(URI.createURI("my.xsd"), true);
```

I'm using the following Maven2 dependencies:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.xsd</groupId>
    <artifactId>xsd</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.emf</groupId>
    <artifactId>ecore</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.emf</groupId>
    <artifactId>common</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.0</version>
</dependency>
```

The code compiles just fine, but produces a RuntimeException at execution time:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: 
    Cannot create a resource for 'my.xsd'; a registered resource factory is needed
    at org.eclipse.emf.ecore.resource.impl.ResourceSetImpl.getResource(ResourceSetImpl.java:346)
```

I found some resource factory implementations in org.eclipse.emf.ecore.xmi, but AFAIK there's only a xmi [snapshot](http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/eclipse/emf/ecore/xmi/2.3.0-v200706262000/xmi-2.3.0-v200706262000.pom) in the public Maven repo, which has a dependency on org.eclipse.core.runtime.. which is *not* what I want.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding this code before creating your ResourceSetImpl:

```
import org.eclipse.xsd.util.XSDResourceFactoryImpl;

Resource.Factory.Registry reg = Resource.Factory.Registry.INSTANCE;
java.util.Map m = reg.getExtensionToFactoryMap();
m.put("xsd", new XSDResourceFactoryImpl());
```

That should create the registry and factory that you need to accomplish what you are trying to do.

Comment: Thanks Keith, that's exactly what I was looking for! Of course I should have found the XSDResourceFactoryImpl in util myself, but I'm totally unfamiliar with the eclipse codebase.