# Java API to parse XSD schema file

Tags: java, xml, xsd

Is there a Java API to parse an XSD schema file?

I found [XSOM](https://xsom.dev.java.net), but it doesn't seem to be maintained anymore.

Comment: What do you want to accomplish? Any XML parser will parse an XSD, it's just an XML file.

Comment: I know it is :) I need to load restriction constrains associated with the schema types. Then I need to convert these to in-the-house  validation system rules. And then validate some complex Java object structure using these rules. Believe me I won't ask question here if I just needed to parse simple XSD file or validate XML against the schema.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/533573/analyzing-xml-schemas-using-org-eclipse-xsd-and-maven2

Comment: [xmlet/XsdParser](https://github.com/xmlet/XsdParser) parses a XSD file into a Java Structure:`String filePath = "Your file path here.";` `XsdParser parserInstance = new XsdParser();` `Stream<XsdElement> elementsStream = parserInstance.parse(filePath);`

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Using standard JDK 6:

```
System.setProperty(DOMImplementationRegistry.PROPERTY, "com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.dom.DOMXSImplementationSourceImpl");
DOMImplementationRegistry registry = DOMImplementationRegistry.newInstance(); 
com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.xs.XSImplementationImpl impl = (XSImplementationImpl) registry.getDOMImplementation("XS-Loader");
XSLoader schemaLoader = impl.createXSLoader(null);
XSModel model = schemaLoader.loadURI("src/test/resources/my.xsd");
```

Comment: forgot to mention that access to these classes are restricted. I use this for tooling only ; don't know if you can use this at runtime.

Comment: It also works without globally changing the DOM parser:
XSImplementation impl = new XSImplementationImpl();

Comment: Hello, I am facins some issue with the reading of the elements and their datatype within the XSD using the `XERCES2` I have posted the question here can you please have look and provide your response if possible?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66856898/how-access-any-element-from-xsd-and-get-its-datatype-and-other-related-informati Thanks

Answer (score 10):

```
public class XsdElements {
    public static void main(String args[]) { 
        try { 
            // parse the document
            DocumentBuilderFactory docBuilderFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            DocumentBuilder docBuilder = docBuilderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
            Document doc = docBuilder.parse (new File("C:/Users/rb054/Desktop/Descriptor.1.5.1.xsd")); 
            NodeList list = doc.getElementsByTagName("xs:element"); 

            //loop to print data
            for(int i = 0 ; i < list.getLength(); i++)
            {
                Element first = (Element)list.item(i);
                if(first.hasAttributes())
                {
                    String nm = first.getAttribute("name"); 
                    System.out.println(nm); 
                    String nm1 = first.getAttribute("type"); 
                    System.out.println(nm1); 
                }
            }
        } 
        catch (ParserConfigurationException e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (SAXException e) 
        { 
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (IOException ed) 
        {
            ed.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: hi this is the simple way to parse a xsd file..

Comment: package definitions would be nice....

Comment: @Nenotlep org.w3c.dom.Document, org.w3c.dom.Element,  org.w3c.dom.NodeList

Comment: @ashutoshsrivastava thanks man!

Comment: If the .xsd passed has an imported xsd, this doesn't work.

Comment: Thanks a lot Roshan for your answer, you saved my time.

Comment: Hello Thanks a lot for this answer. I am trying to parse XSD and found this answer to be useful. However, I have one doubt how can I store all the elements in the same `NODELIST`? in your case you are reading only `xs:element` and storing it into `list` but my XSD has various other tags like `xs:complexType` etc how can I store the all tha tags in same `LIST` and use this single list for my further processing? If you want detailed question I have posted here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66867306/how-to-append-the-elements-to-existing-nodelist-during-the-parse-of-xsd-file-in

Answer (score 4):

We have tended to use Apache Xerces http://xerces.apache.org/. Works really well for us.

Comment: Just parse XSD file? Such approach is very complicated when your schema file contains many compound and complex types declarations.

Comment: Hello, Based on your response I looked into the `XERCES2` xsd parser and tried to implement it but  I am facing some issue with the reading of the elements and their datatype within the XSD using the XERCES2 I have posted the question here can you please have look and provide your response if possible? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66856898/how-access-any-element-from-xsd-and-get-its-datatype-and-other-related-informati Thanks –

Answer (score 4):

You can use XMLBeans http://xmlbeans.apache.org.  For most use cases around XML/Java binding people seem to be moving to JAXB since it is built in.  But for what you want to do, XMLBeans provides access to some great high level data structures that represent schemae in a way that is easy to traverse.

You can start with something like...

```
SchemaTypeSystem sts = XmlBeans.compileXsd(new XmlObject[] {
    XmlObject.Factory.parse(xsdFile) }, XmlBeans.getBuiltinTypeSystem(), null);
```

From there you should be able to figure out how to drill into the SchemaTypeSystem from the JavaDoc.

If someone knows of an alternative that is as convenient and relatively supported, it would be great to know about it.  I'm actively looking.

Answer (score 2):

Try [EasyWSDL](http://easywsdl.ow2.org/) - it can parse both XSD an WSDL specifications.

Comment: Can you please share some code reading data from XSD? I am getting an error "Unknown Version of wsdl" while loading XSD file.

Answer (score 1):

[JAXB](http://jaxb.java.net/)

See this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1172101/is-there-a-standard-java-utility-to-parse-xsd-files-at-runtime)

Comment: Or take a look at JAXP (https://jaxp.dev.java.net/)

Comment: I don't want XML binding nor to parse XSD by hand (i.e. with JAXP). I need API to browse XSD structure, list types defined in the Schema and all restrictions associated with them. I know I can parse XSD with JAXP but for very complex schemas is may be pain in the a*s.

Comment: As others have said, XSD is just a valid XML doc. Use a DOM parser, if you're going to update it or need to navigate it in non-sequential order. A SAX parser would be very efficient if you want to extract elements in sequential order, and it shouldn't be difficult to write, even for long/complex xml - especially if you're just extracting the types and restrictions.

And from the comment you made in your original post, I think you're better off just writing a SAX parser, and converting it to your in-house validation rules.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned, a schema is itself valid XML. What do you want to load it for, validation? If so then there are some handy classes in the `javax.xml.validation` package.

Comment: For validation, but not for validation of the XML file. I need to extract all data types from XSD and then export restrictions associated with the elements to external validation system.

Answer (score 0):

Depends what your specific requirements are. [This page](http://java-source.net/open-source/xml-parsers) gives a good overview of the major options and the use cases they support.

One thing to think about: Depending on the platform you are deploying to and other frameworks you are using, there may already be various APIs in your dependency tree (xerces is particularly common in App Servers for example).  Watch out for version conflicts which can be a nightmare to isolate and debug.

Comment: If you stick with the standard APIs you are much safer.  For example deal with Xerces as a JAXP parser instead of native APIS.  This way if you port to another framework and they are using another JAXP implementation you're still safe.

Comment: Please refer to the comment I wrote to the question. I don't need XML parsing API.