# Parsing XML Schema in Java

Tags: java, parsing, xsd

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Java API to parse XSD schema file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3996857/java-api-to-parse-xsd-schema-file)

It's been a while I've been looking for a Java API that could parse a XML Schema file (such as SAX for XML files) or generate a XML file from it. Does anyone know any?

Thanks in advance,
Paulo S.

Comment: I have deja vu http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=xml+parser+java