# Parsing XSD and getting nested elements 

Tags: java, xsd

After going through [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3996857/java-api-to-parse-xsd-schema-file) page, I wrote the following code to parse an XSD file. However I only get the root element, and I am lost so as to how to get the nested elements inside it.
Code:

```
            XMLSchemaLoader loader = new XMLSchemaLoader();
            XSModel model = loader.loadURI(url.toURI().toString());
            XSNamedMap map = model.getComponents(XSConstants.ELEMENT_DECLARATION);  //returns the root component 

            if(map!=null ){
                for (int j=0; j<map.getLength(); j++) {
                   String name = map.item(j).getName(); //returns 'country' correctly.                    
                }
            }
```

I am not posting the entire xsd, but this is the structure:

```
<xsd:element name="country">
    <xsd:complexType>
        <xsd:annotation>
                <xsd:appinfo id="substring">No</xsd:appinfo>                                                
        </xsd:annotation>
        <xsd:sequence minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded">
            <xsd:element name="states"  minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1" >
                <xsd:complexType>
                    <xsd:annotation>
                            <xsd:appinfo id="substring">No</xsd:appinfo>                                                
                    </xsd:annotation>
                    <xsd:sequence>
                        <xsd:element name="cities" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                        </xsd:element>
                    </xsd:sequence>
                    <xsd:attribute name="name" type="xsd:string" />
                </xsd:complexType>
            </xsd:element>
        </xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:attribute name="name" type="xsd:string"></xsd:attribute>
    </xsd:complexType>
</xsd:element>
```

I am looking to read all the elements, not just the base element, and not sure how to proceed. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Users browse by tags, not by titles. Repeating the main tag `[java]` in title is unnecessary and it would only clutter the entire [list of Java questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java).

Answer (score 1):

I think your trying to iterate over the [`XSNamedMap`](http://xerces.apache.org/xerces2-j/javadocs/xs/org/apache/xerces/xs/XSNamedMap.html) incorrectly. The reason you are getting only the country element is because it is the root element. You will probably have to descend down into [`XSNamespaceItem`](http://xerces.apache.org/xerces2-j/javadocs/xs/org/apache/xerces/xs/XSNamespaceItem.html) and call [`getComponents`](http://xerces.apache.org/xerces2-j/javadocs/xs/org/apache/xerces/xs/XSNamespaceItem.html#getComponents%28short%29) to retrieve another set of `XSNamedMap` objects.

This will properly parse the XSD but you still have to traverse the tree.

Comment: So I should be getting the XSNamespaceItem instead of the XSNamedMap. I see. Thanks. I will try it.

Comment: I was able to do it using the XSParticles inside the XSComplexTypeDecl inside the XSElementDecl, which is an item in the map. Thanks.