# How to make a string tree from xsd file

Tags: java, xsd, xerces

I am trying to parse xsd file and make an Tree of strings with it's hierarchy.
I read the following questions:
[Parsing XSD and getting nested elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8069358/parsing-xsd-and-getting-nested-elements)  ,
[Java API to parse XSD schema file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3996857/java-api-to-parse-xsd-schema-file) .
However, I still don't get it.
I wrote the following code:

```
public class Tree {
    public String Data;
    private Tree Parent;
    private ArrayList<Tree> Children;

    public Tree(String data) {
        Data = data;
        Parent = null;
        Children = new ArrayList<Tree>();
    }

    public Tree AddChild(String data){
        Tree child = new Tree(data);
        child.Parent = this;
        Children.add(child);
        return child;
    }

    public ArrayList<Tree> Children(){
        return Children;
    }

    public Tree Parent(){
        return Parent;
    }

    public static Tree MakeTreeFromXsd(String xsdPath) 
            throws ClassNotFoundException, InstantiationException, 
            IllegalAccessException, ClassCastException{

        System.setProperty(DOMImplementationRegistry.PROPERTY, 
                "com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.dom.DOMXSImplementationSourceImpl");

        DOMImplementationRegistry registry = DOMImplementationRegistry.newInstance();

        com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.xs.XSImplementation impl = 
                (com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.xs.XSImplementation) 
                registry.getDOMImplementation("XS-Loader");

        XSLoader schemaLoader = impl.createXSLoader(null);
        XSModel model = schemaLoader.loadURI(xsdPath);
        XSNamedMap map = model.getComponents(XSConstants.ELEMENT_DECLARATION);
        Tree t = new Tree("root");
        for (int j=0; j<map.getLength(); j++) {
            XSObject o = map.item(j);
            t.AddChild(o.getName());
        }
        return t;
    }
}
```

How can I improve the function MakeTreeFromXsd to return a tree with all the hierarchy of the xsd and not only the top-level components ?

Comment: Refer this for some info on how to get all node details: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8069358/parsing-xsd-and-getting-nested-elements