# How do I parse a .xsd file using Java

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Java API to parse XSD schema file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3996857/java-api-to-parse-xsd-schema-file)

I have a requirement to parse my XML schema file which will be in .xsd extention.

I am familiar with SAX parser , So I want to use this parser to parse my schema , but I read it in forums that I can't parse my XSD file usind SAX parser.

Please let me know which parser/API I need to use to parse my XSD file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `*.xsd` format is perfectly well-formed XML, and so you can indeed parse an XML schema file with a SAX parser.

Now, *why* you'd do that is another story. Usually what you want to do is validate that an XML file adheres to the schema described in the `*.xsd` file; you do that by referencing the schema in the XML file and setting the appropriate properties on the parser factory: it doesn't involved parsing the schema file explicitly yourself.

Answer (score 2):

As Ernest mentioned you could use any XML API. But if you are specifically looking for XSD api then

1. [Eclipse XSD](http://www.eclipse.org/modeling/mdt/?project=xsd#xsd)
2. [XSOM](http://xsom.java.net/)