# Reading an XSD file to get all the elements and corresponding attributes in Java

Tags: java, xml, xsd

My requirement is to read an XSD file and to get all its elements with corresponding attributes in java. I've been trying to convert my XSD file to a sample XML file as parsing an XML file to get all it's elements and attributes is easy. But so far I've been unable to find a good enough tool in java to programmatically convert my XSD to sample XML.

Is there any free and good java code available to convert an XSD to its sample XML?

Or else what is the way I can read all the elements and attributes that a sample XML would contain directly from the XSD file?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: how about using a standard tool for xml binding. JAXB can take xsd files and generate java sources which represent the xml types defined within the schema.
You then could use reflection to determine certain members or relationships in the resulting java classes. Strange requirement leads to strange code

Comment: That's not practical in my case, my xsd file may be huge and I can't have all those java classes running wild :D

Comment: Well, then state your question more clear so that people do not waste their time coming up with solutions not fitting. Wierd requirement. Then I guess you are stuck with parsing the XSD in one way or another, greatly depending on the real requirements. Would pick xslt though as this can extract a lot of information in a neat and powerful way.

Comment: My code is going to receive a xsd file as an input from the client side. Can't help it. Was wondering if there already exists a code package to do what I need, otherwise yeah, I'm stuck with parsing a xsd file.

Answer (score 2):

Processing a raw XSD document as XML is quite tricky except in very simple cases.

Alternatives are:

(a) use an API for accessing a compiled schema (for example, there is such an API in Xerces)

(b) Saxon's schema processor can output an XML representation of the compiled schema, which is much easier to process than the raw XSD documents (for example, it combines everything into one document, and presents the relationship of elements to types in a uniform way).

Answer (score 1):

The xsd format is perfectly valid XML, so you can  parse an XML schema file with any xml parser.

Check this related post to get some code samples and ideas:

[Java API to parse XSD schema file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3996857/java-api-to-parse-xsd-schema-file)

Comment: I know a xsd file is a perfectly valid xml file. However if I parse a xsd file I will get elements such as <xs:complextype> or <xs:sequence>. However the elements and attributes I'm looking for are the ones which a sample xml file conforming to the xsd would contain.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this solves the problem. I have similar requirement of accessing elements and attributes of xsd. Using Eclipse, the solution to create XML out of xsd is quite easy. I have a dynamic web project created and put my xsd in webcontent. Right click on XSD and there is option called 'Generate'. It shows 2 options to generate XML or JAXB classes. On clicking Generate XML, XML file is created from XSD. I hope you were looking for this solution.

Answer (score -1):

There is a tool in java to convert my XSD to sample XML. You need to add jaxb-xjc (executable jar file) in the build path of your project.Once you are done with it just put the .xsd file in src, right click on it and find 'Generate' option, you can now find XML and Jaxb classes against 'Generate' option, Select Xml and get your XML file generated from .xsd.