# How to append the Elements to existing Nodelist during the parse of XSD file in Java DocumentBuilder

Tags: java, xml, dom, xsd

`Application Background`:

Basically, I am building an application in which I am parsing the `XML` document using `SAX PARSER` for every incoming tag I would like to know its `datatype` and other information so I am using the `XSD` associated with that XML file to get the `datatype` and other information related to those tags. Hence, I am parsing the `XSD` file and storing all the information in `Hashmap` so that whenever the tag comes I can pass that `XML TAG` as `key` to my `Hashmap` and obtain the `value` (information associated with it which is obtained during XSD parsing) associated with it.

`Problem I am facing:`

As of now, I am able to parse my `XSD` using the `DocumentBuilderFactory`. But during the collection of elements, I am able to get only one type of element and store it in my `NODELIST` such as elements with tag name `"xs:element"`. My XSD also has some other element type such as `"xs:complexType"`, `xs:any` etc. I would like to read all of them and store them into a single `NODELIST` which I can later loop and push to `HASHMAP`. However I am unable to add any additional elements to my `NODELIST` after adding one type to it:

Below code will add tags with the `xs:element`

`NodeList list = doc.getElementsByTagName("xs:element");`

1. How can I add the tags with `xs:complexType` and `xs:any` to the same `NODELIST`?
2. Is this a good way to find the datatype and other attributes of the `XSD` or any other better approach available. As I may need to hit the `HASHMAP` many times for every TAG in `XML` will there be a performance issue?
3. Is `DocumentBuilderFactory` is a good approach to parse XML or are there any better libaraies for XSD parsing? I looked into `Xerces2` but could not find any good example and I got struck and posted the question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66856898/how-access-any-element-from-xsd-and-get-its-datatype-and-other-related-informati).

Following is my code for parsing the XSD using `DocumentBuilderFactory`:

public class DOMParser {

```
private static Map<String, Element> xmlTags = new HashMap<String, Element>();

public static void main(String[] args) throws URISyntaxException, SAXException, IOException, ParserConfigurationException {
    String xsdPath1 = Paths.get(Xerces2Parser.class.getClassLoader().getResource("test.xsd").toURI()).toFile().getAbsolutePath();
    String filePath1 = Path.of(xsdPath1).toString();

    DocumentBuilderFactory docBuilderFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder docBuilder = docBuilderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
    Document doc = docBuilder.parse(new File(filePath1));
    NodeList list = doc.getElementsByTagName("xs:element");
    System.out.println(list.getLength());
    // How to add the xs:complexType to same list as above
    // list.add(doc.getElementsByTagName("xs:complexType"));
    // list = doc.getElementsByTagName("xs:complexType");

    // Loop and add data to Map for future lookups
    for (int i = 0; i < list.getLength(); i++) {
        Element element = (Element) list.item(i);
        if (element.hasAttributes()) {
            xmlTags.put(element.getAttribute("name"), element);
        }
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score -1):

I don't know what you are trying to achieve (you have described the code you are writing, not the problem it is designed to solve) but what you are doing seems misguided. Trying to get useful information out of an XSD schema by parsing it at the XML level is really hard work, and it's clear from the questions you are asking that you haven't appreciated the complexities of what you are attempting.

It's hard to advise you on the low-level detail of maintaining hash maps and node lists when we don't understand what you are trying to achieve. What information are you trying to extract from the schema, and why?

There are a number of ways of getting information out of a schema at a higher level. Xerces has a Java API for accessing a compiled schema. Saxon has an XML representation of compiled schemas called SCM (the difference from raw XSD is that all the work of expanding xs:include and xs:import, expanding attribute groups, model groups, and substitution groups etc has been done for you). Saxon also has an XPath API (a set of extension functions) for accessing compiled schema information.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. As I have mentioned in my question, I am trying to obtain the data type and other attributes from the XSD which I need for my further processing. I need to convert the XML to JSON so during the conversion I want to know what is the data type for each element of the XML hence I am using the `HASHMAP` which is created from the `XSD` to get the information for the respective XML tag.

Comment: Well, to know the governing type of each element you need to do a lot more than that. You need to distinguish multiple element declarations with the same name; you need to follow the type derivation hierarchy and substitution groups, you need to look at element wildcard particles, and you need to understand how it's affected by `xsi:type`. So far, you're only scratching the surface.

Comment: Actually, in the `NodeList` I am getting all the information I need for each element. As of now, I am getting the information related to the elements which have the tag `xs:element` in XSD. I just want to know if there is a way to add information in a similar way for the elements which have the tag `xs:complexType` to the same `NODELIST`. I know I can create another NODELIST for `xs:complexType` but I am trying to skip that step so that I can have only one `NODELIST` with all the information.

Comment: I'm not going to help you implement a poor design, sorry.